# Highlight polygon and tint rest of map using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to display a highlighted polygon using Google Maps. The idea is that the polygon in question would be displayed normally and the rest of the map should be darkened a little bit.

So, is this even possible do this with Google Map API's? If yes, with what version (v2, v3)? Would it be easier to do it with other map toolkits, like openlayers?

**PS:** One idea I had, was to build an inverse polygon (in this example, the whole world minus the shape of austria) and then display a black colored overlay with transparency using this inverted polygon. But that seems to be quite complicated to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Google Maps API v3 lets you draw [polygons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polygon) with holes. Here's Google's [Pentagon](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/pentagon.html) example. It is much easier than trying to invert a polygon. Basically, create coordinates for a giant polygon that is bigger than you would ever need. That will always be the first polygon in your polygon array. The area you are highlighting will always be the second polygon.

Here's some code to change Google's [Bermuda Triangle demo](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple.html) to use a polygon with a hole:

```
  var everythingElse = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(90, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(90, 90),
  ];



  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ];




  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [everythingElse, triangleCoords],
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#000000",
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Out of the box it doesn't work. It works when everythingElse is clockwise and triangleCoords is counter-clockwise or viceversa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494474/google-maps-api-polygon-with-hole-in-center

Answer (score 7):

USING GEOJSON

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

```
 // define map properties
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.075984, 78.877656),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
//create google map 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

// define geojson
    var geojson = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [0, 90],
                        [180, 90],
                        [180, -90],
                        [0, -90],
                        [-180, -90],
                        [-180, 0],
                        [-180, 90],
                        [0, 90]
                    ],
                    [
                        [79.56298828125, 25.18505888358067],
                        [76.53076171875, 21.37124437061832],
                        [83.38623046875, 21.24842223562701],
                        [79.56298828125, 25.18505888358067]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {}
        }]
    };
//add geojson to map
    map.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
```

incase of external geojson file use

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('url-to-geojson-file');
```

note: google used .json as extension for geojson file and not .geojson
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

create your geojson here
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geojson/

working example
 https://jsfiddle.net/841emtey/5/

Answer (score 3):

With regard to:

> the rest of the map should be darkened a little bit.

This can be done with with Maps API v3 using [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

There's even a [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) where you can play with the settings, and then press `Show JSON` to get the array to pass as the first argument to `new google.maps.StyledMapType`.

To get the effect you want just reduce the `Lightness` for everything, in the wizard you'll want to see this in the `Map Style` box on the right:

```
Feature type:   all
Element type:   all
Lightness:  -70
```

Which will export to:

```
[
  {
     "stylers": [
      { "lightness": -70 }
    ]
  }
]
```

And [look like this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=2&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=lightness%3a-70).