# Google Maps API Polygon with "Hole" In Center

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

Inserting a polygon inside another polygon is supposed to make a "hole" in the center (see the Google maps Pentagon example). However, my program keeps failing to make a hole and instead makes two layers of polygon lines insead.

http://cl.ly/1c243E1V1G2M1D3H3c0O <-- image of my map

Someone said changing the coordinate order fixed their problem so I selected exactly the coordinates of the bermuda triangle as given by Google in their example, however, it had the same problem I encountered before. The relevant code is below:

```
    var everythingElse = [
       new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -82.190262),
       new google.maps.LatLng(17.466465, -65.118292),
       new google.maps.LatLng(34.321384, -63.75737),
       new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -82.190262)
     ];

    var circleOverlay = [
       new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
       new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
       new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
       new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
     ];

    PropertySearch.tintPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
         paths: [ everythingElse, circleOverlay ],
        strokeColor: "#000000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#000000",
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });

    PropertySearch.tintPolygon.setMap(PropertySearch.map);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It really is a matter of direction of indices in your polygons, while one is clockwise other should be counter-clockwise.
Change your second array to:

```
var circleOverlay = [
   new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
   new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),  //second and third coordinates
   new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292), //are swapped compared to your original
   new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
 ];
```

and it will display a nice hole in your triangle