# Create holes on  overlay on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create two google maps api overlays such that one overlay is containing another small overlay.And another small overlay should be transparent. Like a donut. But I could not create such shape because if I make inner overlay transparent then outer overlay fill the color. I want to make such type of shape on google map-[image: I want to make such type of shape on google map-]

It may be circle or polygon. I tried this but not working for me.

```
var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: latlng,
      radius: 100000,
      editable: true,
      zIndex:100
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

    var populationOptions1 = {
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#ccffcc",
          fillOpacity: 0.00,
          map: map,
          center: latlng,
          radius: 10000,
          editable: true,
          zIndex:1000
        };
        cityCircle1 = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions1);
```

How to achieve this shape on google map that blue area will colored and white area will transparent?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Polygon with "Hole" In Center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494474/google-maps-api-polygon-with-hole-in-center)

Comment: Not a duplicate; the Maps API's Circle and Polygon objects have very different capabilities. A Polygon has one outer ring and zero or more inner rings (holes). A Circle is just a single circle with a center and a radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my answer. [this link](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/poly/pentagon.html?r=40) was very useful. It works for me...

[Another example of a "donut" polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html), the key being the winding direction of the path of the inner "hole" path needs to be opposite that of the outer path.