# google map create donut polygon from xml

Tags: xml, google-maps, polygon

I have a page at http://www.choptankelectric.com/outages/google/cec_create_xml.html where there are several polygons some of which contain 'donut' holes which should be transparent but are greyed out.

The coordinates come from an XML file and should look like http://www.choptankelectric.com/outages/index.html which uses a very bulky included file and is inelegant. The XML is generated from coordinates held in a mySQL DB table. Each polygon has a polygonID and (in the case of inner polygons) a field showing the parent outer polygon which contains it.

How can I get it to display with transparent donut holes?

The code is thus:

```
var phpscript = "cec_create_xml.php"; // creates xml data for polygons
downloadUrl(phpscript, function(data) {
   var polygons = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("polygon");
   for (var a = 0; a < polygons.length; a++) {
   //for (var a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
      var Parent = polygons[a].getAttribute("Parent");
      var strokeColor = polygons[a].getAttribute("strokeColor");
      var strokeOpacity = polygons[a].getAttribute("strokeOpacity");
      var strokeWeight = polygons[a].getAttribute("strokeWeight");
      var fillColor = polygons[a].getAttribute("fillColor");
      var fillOpacity = polygons[a].getAttribute("fillOpacity");
      var pts = [[]];
      var points = polygons[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
         pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")),
         parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      }
      var polyOptions = {
         paths: pts,
         strokeColor: strokeColor,
         strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
         strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
         fillColor: fillColor,
         fillOpacity: fillOpacity
      }
      varCECarea = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
      CECarea.bindTo('map',map,'polymap');
   }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force Google Maps to draw polygons with overlapping paths as a union rather than intersection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769380/can-i-force-google-maps-to-draw-polygons-with-overlapping-paths-as-a-union-rathe) (make the inner "hole" paths wind the opposite direction from the outer paths).

Comment: I've tried reversing the paths of the inner polygons but with the same result. On the  http://www.choptankelectric.com/outages/index.html map (which displays correctly) the inner polygon array is contained within the outer polygon array but I don't know enough JS to be able to reproduce it in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the polygons which have parents are not being processed as part of the parents path(s), as it sounds like you are aware in your latest comment. When you have multi-polygons like these parents are intended to be, you pass all their paths at once into the 'paths' property of your google.maps.PolygonOptions object (or when calling Polygon.setPaths() as the first argument) as an array of arrays which each contain a polygon path.
The exact segment of code you posted above, change it to the following:

```
var phpscript = "cec_create_xml.php"; // creates xml data for polygons
downloadUrl(phpscript, function(data) {
    var i, poly, id, parent,
        parentPolys = {},
        childPolys = [],
        polyXml = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("polygon"),
        len = polyXml.length;

    function jsPolyFromXmlPoly(xmlPolygon) {
        var i, pt, lat, lng,
            obj = {
                paths : [[]],
                id : xmlPolygon.getAttribute('PolygonID'),
                parent : xmlPolygon.getAttribute("Parent"),
                strokeColor : xmlPolygon.getAttribute("strokeColor"),
                strokeOpacity : xmlPolygon.getAttribute("strokeOpacity"),
                strokeWeight : xmlPolygon.getAttribute("strokeWeight"),
                fillColor : xmlPolygon.getAttribute("fillColor"),
                fillOpacity : xmlPolygon.getAttribute("fillOpacity")
            },
            pts = xmlPolygon.getElementsByTagName('point'),
            len = pts.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            pt = pts[i];
            lat = Number(pt.getAttribute('lat'));
            lng = Number(pt.getAttribute('lng'));
            obj.paths[0].push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
        return obj;
    }

     //begin filtering & separating child polygons and parent polygons,
     //first converting to javascript object rather than xml
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        poly = jsPolyFromXmlPoly(polyXml[i]);
        id = poly.id;
        parent = poly.parent;
        if (parent === '0') {
            parentPolys[id] = poly;
        } else {
            childPolys.push(poly);
        }
    }
     //begin pushing all the child polygons paths into their parents 'paths' array
    for (i = 0, len = childPolys.length; i < len; i++) {
        poly = childPolys[i];
        id = poly.parent;
        parent = parentPolys[id];
        parent.paths.push(poly.paths[0]);
    }
     //create google maps polygons using only the parent polygons,
     //as they now contain all the child polygon paths
    for (i in parentPolys) {
        poly = parentPolys[i];
        var polyOptions = {
            paths: poly.paths,
            strokeColor: poly.strokeColor,
            strokeOpacity: poly.strokeOpacity,
            strokeWeight: poly.strokeWeight,
            fillColor: poly.fillColor,
            fillOpacity: poly.fillOpacity
        };
        var CECarea = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
        CECarea.bindTo('map', map, 'polymap');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. Many thanks. Thanks also for the comments in the code - I'll go through it now and try to understand it.