# Adding hole in polygon with google maps for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I would like to darken the entire map in my application except for a small "selected" part that is shown normally.

To do that feature in *Google Maps API for Android* I created a polygon and I called the `setHoles` function like this :

```
List points = Arrays.asList(new LatLng(-90 + delta, -180 + delta),
                new LatLng(-90 + delta, 0),
                new LatLng(-90 + delta, 180 - delta),
                new LatLng(0, 180 - delta),
                new LatLng(90 - delta, 180 - delta),
                new LatLng(90 - delta, 0),
                new LatLng(90 - delta, -180 + delta),
                new LatLng(0, -180 + delta));
defaultZone = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().addAll(points));
defaultZone.setFillColor(0x99000000);

defaultZone.setHoles(Arrays.asList(pointsLatLong));
```

This was working great for *Android* and I wanted to reproduce the same effect in the *iOS* application but the `GMSPolygon` class does not have the `setHoles` function and I can't figure out how I can create holes in my polygon (I tried to draw the dark polygon on the map and then draw the "selected" zone with a transparent color above it but it doe snot work).

Can someone help me? That seems strange that a feature could be done in *Android* but not in *iOS* with the same framework

Comment: See if this solves your problem [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494474/google-maps-api-polygon-with-hole-in-center).

Comment: @larryp I saw this question but it does not work for me. I tried to change the direction of one of the polygons but it gives me weird polygons. I think that can be because I create the polygon with only 1 path, but there is no way to create a polygon with 2 paths with iOS :(

Answer (score 1):

swift

```
override func loadView() {
  let hydeParkLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.87344, longitude: 151.21135)
  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: hydeParkLocation, zoom: 16)
  let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
  mapView.animate(to: camera)

  let hydePark = "tpwmEkd|y[QVe@Pk@BsHe@mGc@iNaAKMaBIYIq@qAMo@Eo@@[Fe@DoALu@HUb@c@XUZS^ELGxOhAd@@ZB`@J^BhFRlBN\\BZ@`AFrATAJAR?rAE\\C~BIpD"
  let archibaldFountain = "tlvmEqq|y[NNCXSJQOB[TI"
  let reflectionPool = "bewmEwk|y[Dm@zAPEj@{AO"

  let polygon = GMSPolygon()
  polygon.path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: hydePark)
  polygon.holes = [GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: archibaldFountain)!, GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: reflectionPool)!]
  polygon.fillColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.2)
  polygon.strokeColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
  polygon.strokeWidth = 2
  polygon.map = mapView
  view = mapView
}
```

objective-c

```
- (void)loadView {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D hydeParkLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.87344, 151.21135);
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:hydeParkLocation
                                                             zoom:16];
  _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

  NSString *hydePark = @"tpwmEkd|y[QVe@Pk@BsHe@mGc@iNaAKMaBIYIq@qAMo@Eo@@[Fe@DoALu@HUb@c@XUZS^ELGxOhAd@@ZB`@J^BhFRlBN\\BZ@`AFrATAJAR?rAE\\C~BIpD";
  NSString *archibaldFountain = @"tlvmEqq|y[NNCXSJQOB[TI";
  NSString *reflectionPool = @"bewmEwk|y[Dm@zAPEj@{AO";

  GMSPolygon *polygon = [[GMSPolygon alloc] init];
  polygon.path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:hydePark];
  polygon.holes = @[[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:archibaldFountain],
                    [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:reflectionPool]];
  polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.2];
  polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
  polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
  polygon.map = _mapView;
  self.view = _mapView;
}
```

[reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#create_a_hollow_polygon)

Comment: Just got from google maps, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#create_a_hollow_polygon

Comment: i follow this piece of code from the google documentation and its working fine but when I only change the Location Coordinate, It does not show the polygon on that location...! or highlight that location...! Can you explain how to draw or highlight that location? Is there anything I am missing.?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the iOS SDK. The request is being tracked here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5464

Go vote it up!

Comment: There is a partial workaround if there's only 1 hole. It looks like you can include 1 hole in the path and it will render correctly. This is obviously not a solution, so proper support needs to be added to the SDK.

Comment: I only need 1 hole but i can't make it work. How should the path look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known request, Google will include that most likely in the next iOS maps SDK release.

Comment for it on this link https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5464