# GeoJSON MultiPolygon rendering

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a question regarding the GeoJSON Feature and Multipolygons.

The requirement is to display a map with all german ZIP Code Areas. Some of them are fully enclosed in others and need to be cut out of their parents.

Following the [GeoJSON specs](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) I created a feature with a geometry node looking like this:

```
{
"type": "MultiPolygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[
[
6.9210873,
50.56554
],
[
6.923955,
50.56846
],
[
6.927969,
50.56992
],
[
6.9331307,
50.570408
],
[
6.9342775,
50.57138
],
[
6.9314103,
50.57284
],
[
6.9291162,
50.57284
],
[
6.927969,
50.573814
],
[
6.927969,
50.57479
],
[
6.927396,
50.575275
],
[
6.9256754,
50.575275
],
[
6.9256754,
50.57625
],
[
6.9262486,
50.577225
],
[
6.926822,
50.578686
],
[
6.923955,
50.578686
],
[
6.9210873,
50.578197
],
[
6.9199405,
50.578197
],
[
6.919367,
50.578686
],
[
6.91822,
50.578686
],
[
6.916499,
50.578686
],
[
6.9153523,
50.576736
],
[
6.916499,
50.576736
],
[
6.917073,
50.57625
],
[
6.9176464,
50.57625
],
[
6.919367,
50.57625
],
[
6.9199405,
50.573814
],
[
6.919367,
50.57187
],
[
6.91822,
50.57138
],
[
6.917073,
50.57187
],
[
6.915926,
50.57187
],
[
6.9147787,
50.57138
],
[
6.912485,
50.573814
],
[
6.9130583,
50.57479
],
[
6.9147787,
50.575275
],
[
6.9147787,
50.576736
],
[
6.9147787,
50.578197
],
[
6.912485,
50.57771
],
[
6.9119115,
50.578686
],
[
6.910191,
50.57917
],
[
6.9061766,
50.576736
],
[
6.903309,
50.575764
],
[
6.9015884,
50.57333
],
[
6.902162,
50.57138
],
[
6.9015884,
50.570408
],
[
6.899295,
50.570892
],
[
6.899295,
50.57333
],
[
6.897574,
50.57479
],
[
6.896427,
50.57479
],
[
6.89528,
50.57333
],
[
6.891839,
50.57479
],
[
6.891266,
50.577225
],
[
6.8924127,
50.57966
],
[
6.8924127,
50.581604
],
[
6.8929863,
50.582092
],
[
6.8924127,
50.584038
],
[
6.891839,
50.585987
],
[
6.8924127,
50.58745
],
[
6.891839,
50.587936
],
[
6.8895454,
50.58842
],
[
6.888972,
50.587936
],
[
6.8872514,
50.58891
],
[
6.887825,
50.59037
],
[
6.886104,
50.59183
],
[
6.8849573,
50.59475
],
[
6.8849573,
50.598644
],
[
6.8843837,
50.59962
],
[
6.8843837,
50.600105
],
[
6.8855305,
50.600594
],
[
6.8866777,
50.601566
],
[
6.888972,
50.602055
],
[
6.890692,
50.603027
],
[
6.896427,
50.603027
],
[
6.8981476,
50.604
],
[
6.902162,
50.604
],
[
6.9027357,
50.603027
],
[
6.9050293,
50.602055
],
[
6.909044,
50.603027
],
[
6.910191,
50.604977
],
[
6.912485,
50.604977
],
[
6.913632,
50.60546
],
[
6.9142056,
50.60595
],
[
6.9142056,
50.606434
],
[
6.910191,
50.60741
],
[
6.9067497,
50.60887
],
[
6.904456,
50.609356
],
[
6.9067497,
50.611305
],
[
6.910191,
50.616173
],
[
6.911338,
50.617146
],
[
6.9119115,
50.620556
],
[
6.913632,
50.623478
],
[
6.9142056,
50.62445
],
[
6.915926,
50.62591
],
[
6.916499,
50.62932
],
[
6.913632,
50.629807
],
[
6.9142056,
50.63078
],
[
6.911338,
50.63078
],
[
6.9119115,
50.63224
],
[
6.9107647,
50.63273
],
[
6.9096174,
50.63224
],
[
6.907324,
50.63224
],
[
6.9038825,
50.633213
],
[
6.902162,
50.634674
],
[
6.899295,
50.635647
],
[
6.899295,
50.635647
],
[
6.888398,
50.636623
],
[
6.8849573,
50.63808
],
[
6.8849573,
50.636135
],
[
6.8786488,
50.637108
],
[
6.8734875,
50.63857
],
[
6.8734875,
50.64003
],
[
6.8700466,
50.64149
],
[
6.871767,
50.641975
],
[
6.87234,
50.642464
],
[
6.8711934,
50.644413
],
[
6.87234,
50.64733
],
[
6.863738,
50.651714
],
[
6.860297,
50.650253
],
[
6.858003,
50.653175
],
[
6.8620176,
50.65415
],
[
6.863738,
50.65512
],
[
6.866032,
50.65512
],
[
6.8654585,
50.65561
],
[
6.864885,
50.65561
],
[
6.863738,
50.65658
],
[
6.861444,
50.65756
],
[
6.861444,
50.65853
],
[
6.861444,
50.660965
],
[
6.8654585,
50.660965
],
[
6.8666053,
50.667294
],
[
6.867179,
50.670216
],
[
6.8734875,
50.670216
],
[
6.875781,
50.675083
],
[
6.871767,
50.676544
],
[
6.8746343,
50.678978
],
[
6.8711934,
50.679955
],
[
6.872914,
50.68239
],
[
6.8734875,
50.68531
],
[
6.8769283,
50.690178
],
[
6.8769283,
50.690666
],
[
6.8711934,
50.689205
],
[
6.856856,
50.69115
],
[
6.85915,
50.694557
],
[
6.8545623,
50.69748
],
[
6.8545623,
50.69748
],
[
6.853415,
50.69602
],
[
6.8488274,
50.696995
],
[
6.8407984,
50.703323
],
[
6.8350635,
50.701374
],
[
6.820726,
50.701862
],
[
6.817285,
50.701862
],
[
6.817285,
50.699913
],
[
6.814991,
50.699913
],
[
6.8144174,
50.701374
],
[
6.81155,
50.701374
],
[
6.810403,
50.69894
],
[
6.805815,
50.69943
],
[
6.8052416,
50.69748
],
[
6.8052416,
50.694073
],
[
6.804668,
50.6931
],
[
6.8052416,
50.692123
],
[
6.803521,
50.692123
],
[
6.7995067,
50.690666
],
[
6.7949185,
50.690666
],
[
6.7949185,
50.689205
],
[
6.777714,
50.69164
],
[
6.776567,
50.69164
],
[
6.7656703,
50.686283
],
[
6.7610826,
50.689205
],
[
6.760509,
50.68969
],
[
6.762803,
50.69164
],
[
6.7656703,
50.695045
],
[
6.7656703,
50.695045
],
[
6.746172,
50.699913
],
[
6.738143,
50.7004
],
[
6.738143,
50.701374
],
[
6.7318344,
50.701374
],
[
6.7289667,
50.696507
],
[
6.726673,
50.697968
],
[
6.724379,
50.69602
],
[
6.719791,
50.69261
],
[
6.718644,
50.693584
],
[
6.7146297,
50.69115
],
[
6.710615,
50.693584
],
[
6.7066007,
50.690178
],
[
6.7123356,
50.687256
],
[
6.709468,
50.684334
],
[
6.711762,
50.68336
],
[
6.7100415,
50.68141
],
[
6.7134824,
50.679466
],
[
6.717497,
50.678005
],
[
6.717497,
50.677032
],
[
6.720938,
50.675083
],
[
6.723232,
50.676544
],
[
6.7249527,
50.676544
],
[
6.725526,
50.677032
],
[
6.725526,
50.679466
],
[
6.7318344,
50.678493
],
[
6.725526,
50.67265
],
[
6.723232,
50.67119
],
[
6.7289667,
50.668755
],
[
6.726673,
50.66681
],
[
6.725526,
50.66486
],
[
6.7238054,
50.661938
],
[
6.7226586,
50.65853
],
[
6.7215114,
50.65512
],
[
6.7215114,
50.652203
],
[
6.717497,
50.651714
],
[
6.7152033,
50.64782
],
[
6.7134824,
50.64733
],
[
6.711762,
50.645874
],
[
6.7134824,
50.644897
],
[
6.7134824,
50.644897
],
[
6.7134824,
50.642464
],
[
6.7157764,
50.64149
],
[
6.714056,
50.637596
],
[
6.7146297,
50.637108
],
[
6.714056,
50.636623
],
[
6.7157764,
50.635647
],
[
6.7152033,
50.634186
],
[
6.71635,
50.6337
],
[
6.7157764,
50.63224
],
[
6.71635,
50.63224
],
[
6.7152033,
50.627373
],
[
6.71635,
50.627373
],
[
6.7180705,
50.627857
],
[
6.719791,
50.625423
],
[
6.7215114,
50.62445
],
[
6.720938,
50.623962
],
[
6.7260995,
50.62104
],
[
6.7272463,
50.618607
],
[
6.7283936,
50.618607
],
[
6.7295403,
50.617146
],
[
6.734702,
50.614227
],
[
6.735849,
50.6152
],
[
6.74101,
50.614227
],
[
6.7444515,
50.61471
],
[
6.7455983,
50.615685
],
[
6.746172,
50.61666
],
[
6.7478924,
50.61666
],
[
6.7478924,
50.615685
],
[
6.750186,
50.615685
],
[
6.7507596,
50.61179
],
[
6.757068,
50.61325
],
[
6.769685,
50.615685
],
[
6.768538,
50.61374
],
[
6.770832,
50.61179
],
[
6.7702584,
50.603027
],
[
6.7702584,
50.603027
],
[
6.7771406,
50.603516
],
[
6.7782874,
50.604
],
[
6.7771406,
50.606434
],
[
6.7834487,
50.60887
],
[
6.787463,
50.60741
],
[
6.78689,
50.60546
],
[
6.790331,
50.606922
],
[
6.7914777,
50.609356
],
[
6.7937717,
50.60887
],
[
6.7949185,
50.608383
],
[
6.795492,
50.609844
],
[
6.798933,
50.609356
],
[
6.802374,
50.60887
],
[
6.8052416,
50.60741
],
[
6.8075356,
50.606922
],
[
6.809256,
50.606434
],
[
6.8144174,
50.60887
],
[
6.816138,
50.604977
],
[
6.8167114,
50.602055
],
[
6.8224463,
50.595726
],
[
6.8167114,
50.592316
],
[
6.818432,
50.58891
],
[
6.8138437,
50.587936
],
[
6.814991,
50.577225
],
[
6.8121233,
50.575764
],
[
6.8190055,
50.56213
],
[
6.8333426,
50.566998
],
[
6.841945,
50.56408
],
[
6.8545623,
50.564564
],
[
6.871767,
50.570892
],
[
6.8780756,
50.56554
],
[
6.8947067,
50.561646
],
[
6.897574,
50.56213
],
[
6.9027357,
50.56262
],
[
6.904456,
50.56408
],
[
6.9067497,
50.565052
],
[
6.909044,
50.566513
],
[
6.9119115,
50.566998
],
[
6.912485,
50.56554
],
[
6.913632,
50.56408
],
[
6.916499,
50.565052
],
[
6.917073,
50.56408
],
[
6.9210873,
50.56554
],
[
6.9210873,
50.56554
]
],
[
[
6.7610826,
50.64733
],
[
6.762803,
50.63857
],
[
6.768538,
50.636135
],
[
6.7771406,
50.641003
],
[
6.7782874,
50.643436
],
[
6.779434,
50.643925
],
[
6.7857428,
50.64149
],
[
6.7943454,
50.64052
],
[
6.79836,
50.64149
],
[
6.804095,
50.651714
],
[
6.8086824,
50.65074
],
[
6.809256,
50.653175
],
[
6.809256,
50.654636
],
[
6.817285,
50.654636
],
[
6.8178587,
50.65512
],
[
6.8218727,
50.65853
],
[
6.820726,
50.659504
],
[
6.8218727,
50.660965
],
[
6.818432,
50.662426
],
[
6.8132706,
50.662914
],
[
6.8121233,
50.662914
],
[
6.8132706,
50.6634
],
[
6.8132706,
50.66437
],
[
6.81155,
50.66486
],
[
6.81155,
50.667294
],
[
6.81155,
50.668755
],
[
6.8086824,
50.669243
],
[
6.806962,
50.669727
],
[
6.8052416,
50.670216
],
[
6.8018007,
50.670704
],
[
6.7966394,
50.670704
],
[
6.795492,
50.67265
],
[
6.795492,
50.673138
],
[
6.7857428,
50.675083
],
[
6.7771406,
50.67411
],
[
6.771979,
50.67265
],
[
6.7668176,
50.670216
],
[
6.765097,
50.668266
],
[
6.7633767,
50.66486
],
[
6.762803,
50.662914
],
[
6.7610826,
50.65902
],
[
6.7610826,
50.65756
],
[
6.7610826,
50.65658
],
[
6.7610826,
50.64733
],
[
6.7610826,
50.64733
]
]
]
]
}
```

The Coordinates Object is an Array of Polygons, in this case only one, with the first key being the outer line, the second element is the inner Polygon.

Using http://geojsonlint.com/ everything displays as excpected and I also have other Polygons build the same way (a class that can only create this structure) and they work like a charm.

But inside Google Maps it draws a polyline inside the parent and does not spare out the color. (The Child element comes into place and so the inner spot is darker than all other elements)

I cleared the cache, changed browsers and even moved to another PC, so I assume it's not a client side cache issue.

another, more complex Situation comes in with this Area, the nice City of Rheine:

```
{
"type": "MultiPolygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[
[
7.463039,
52.341152
],
[
7.4584513,
52.334335
],
[
7.4773765,
52.334824
],
[
7.4808173,
52.32898
],
[
7.4802437,
52.32314
],
[
7.4831114,
52.32314
],
[
7.4985957,
52.317783
],
[
7.498022,
52.316322
],
[
7.5100656,
52.3134
],
[
7.5123596,
52.3134
],
[
7.512933,
52.314373
],
[
7.515227,
52.314373
],
[
7.5146537,
52.315834
],
[
7.5158005,
52.317783
],
[
7.518668,
52.315834
],
[
7.5192413,
52.316322
],
[
7.5203886,
52.31486
],
[
7.5215354,
52.31194
],
[
7.523256,
52.312428
],
[
7.5249763,
52.311455
],
[
7.523256,
52.31048
],
[
7.5249763,
52.309994
],
[
7.5261235,
52.31048
],
[
7.5272703,
52.309017
],
[
7.5318584,
52.306583
],
[
7.549063,
52.29003
],
[
7.552504,
52.28711
],
[
7.555945,
52.283215
],
[
7.558239,
52.28078
],
[
7.559386,
52.27932
],
[
7.5588126,
52.27883
],
[
7.5588126,
52.276398
],
[
7.5611067,
52.276398
],
[
7.562827,
52.274937
],
[
7.5611067,
52.274452
],
[
7.559386,
52.27104
],
[
7.559386,
52.27007
],
[
7.5553713,
52.266663
],
[
7.558239,
52.265686
],
[
7.5588126,
52.264225
],
[
7.553651,
52.259357
],
[
7.572003,
52.254
],
[
7.5754437,
52.252056
],
[
7.580032,
52.25303
],
[
7.5817523,
52.250595
],
[
7.5806055,
52.250595
],
[
7.5840464,
52.23599
],
[
7.5869136,
52.22917
],
[
7.5869136,
52.22917
],
[
7.585193,
52.22917
],
[
7.585193,
52.228683
],
[
7.5760174,
52.22625
],
[
7.5679884,
52.22479
],
[
7.5651207,
52.223816
],
[
7.5634003,
52.222355
],
[
7.5622535,
52.221382
],
[
7.56168,
52.22187
],
[
7.559386,
52.220894
],
[
7.552504,
52.21797
],
[
7.553651,
52.217
],
[
7.552504,
52.217
],
[
7.5519304,
52.217487
],
[
7.55021,
52.216515
],
[
7.549063,
52.216515
],
[
7.546769,
52.215538
],
[
7.5375934,
52.216515
],
[
7.534152,
52.217
],
[
7.5324316,
52.216515
],
[
7.5284176,
52.21846
],
[
7.523256,
52.21992
],
[
7.523256,
52.21895
],
[
7.5261235,
52.217
],
[
7.5244026,
52.21408
],
[
7.5249763,
52.21262
],
[
7.523256,
52.21213
],
[
7.522682,
52.21067
],
[
7.5215354,
52.210182
],
[
7.516374,
52.210182
],
[
7.5158005,
52.206776
],
[
7.5123596,
52.208725
],
[
7.508345,
52.206776
],
[
7.506624,
52.20775
],
[
7.506051,
52.207264
],
[
7.5031834,
52.206287
],
[
7.5071983,
52.20288
],
[
7.4865522,
52.196552
],
[
7.469921,
52.191196
],
[
7.459598,
52.193146
],
[
7.446408,
52.19217
],
[
7.4441137,
52.19363
],
[
7.441246,
52.193146
],
[
7.441246,
52.193146
],
[
7.440673,
52.197525
],
[
7.445261,
52.198498
],
[
7.4441137,
52.20142
],
[
7.440673,
52.200935
],
[
7.4395256,
52.200935
],
[
7.438379,
52.20288
],
[
7.429776,
52.198986
],
[
7.428056,
52.203854
],
[
7.4228945,
52.20337
],
[
7.4171596,
52.21895
],
[
7.4137187,
52.22917
],
[
7.412572,
52.228683
],
[
7.4102774,
52.23599
],
[
7.407984,
52.24475
],
[
7.4102774,
52.25254
],
[
7.407984,
52.25254
],
[
7.40741,
52.252056
],
[
7.4062634,
52.257896
],
[
7.4045424,
52.258385
],
[
7.4039693,
52.26082
],
[
7.4022484,
52.264713
],
[
7.4022484,
52.2652
],
[
7.3930726,
52.26179
],
[
7.391926,
52.264225
],
[
7.3856173,
52.26374
],
[
7.38275,
52.26861
],
[
7.3810296,
52.269096
],
[
7.3764415,
52.27786
],
[
7.3718534,
52.283703
],
[
7.3661184,
52.292953
],
[
7.3661184,
52.292953
],
[
7.37128,
52.299767
],
[
7.3867645,
52.309017
],
[
7.388485,
52.308044
],
[
7.3976607,
52.3061
],
[
7.399955,
52.308044
],
[
7.400528,
52.310966
],
[
7.402822,
52.310966
],
[
7.402822,
52.311455
],
[
7.4039693,
52.312428
],
[
7.413145,
52.311455
],
[
7.4263353,
52.31389
],
[
7.43035,
52.322163
],
[
7.438379,
52.332874
],
[
7.438379,
52.332874
],
[
7.44354,
52.334824
],
[
7.4441137,
52.334824
],
[
7.463039,
52.341152
],
[
7.463039,
52.341152
]
],
[
[
7.4320703,
52.29587
],
[
7.4332175,
52.2949
],
[
7.434938,
52.291004
],
[
7.434938,
52.288082
],
[
7.4360847,
52.284187
],
[
7.437232,
52.28224
],
[
7.4418197,
52.27883
],
[
7.44354,
52.27737
],
[
7.448128,
52.273964
],
[
7.4498487,
52.27299
],
[
7.452716,
52.272503
],
[
7.454437,
52.27104
],
[
7.45501,
52.267147
],
[
7.456731,
52.26374
],
[
7.4578776,
52.26228
],
[
7.4578776,
52.26228
],
[
7.463039,
52.26179
],
[
7.4664803,
52.263252
],
[
7.4659066,
52.264713
],
[
7.473362,
52.265686
],
[
7.4854054,
52.27104
],
[
7.481391,
52.273964
],
[
7.4865522,
52.274452
],
[
7.4905667,
52.274452
],
[
7.492861,
52.286137
],
[
7.492861,
52.28857
],
[
7.487126,
52.289543
],
[
7.481964,
52.287598
],
[
7.474509,
52.29782
],
[
7.47795,
52.299282
],
[
7.474509,
52.300743
],
[
7.474509,
52.30269
],
[
7.4693475,
52.3061
],
[
7.4664803,
52.304638
],
[
7.45501,
52.303177
],
[
7.4498487,
52.302204
],
[
7.4446874,
52.302204
],
[
7.4320703,
52.29587
],
[
7.4320703,
52.29587
]
],
[
[
7.4320703,
52.29587
],
[
7.4332175,
52.2949
],
[
7.434938,
52.291004
],
[
7.434938,
52.288082
],
[
7.4360847,
52.284187
],
[
7.437232,
52.28224
],
[
7.4418197,
52.27883
],
[
7.44354,
52.27737
],
[
7.448128,
52.273964
],
[
7.4498487,
52.27299
],
[
7.452716,
52.272503
],
[
7.454437,
52.27104
],
[
7.45501,
52.267147
],
[
7.456731,
52.26374
],
[
7.4578776,
52.26228
],
[
7.4578776,
52.26228
],
[
7.4578776,
52.26082
],
[
7.456157,
52.258873
],
[
7.45501,
52.257896
],
[
7.453863,
52.256924
],
[
7.442967,
52.256435
],
[
7.431497,
52.259357
],
[
7.4263353,
52.26082
],
[
7.4171596,
52.26082
],
[
7.4137187,
52.26228
],
[
7.4068365,
52.269096
],
[
7.402822,
52.274937
],
[
7.3982344,
52.28224
],
[
7.3982344,
52.28565
],
[
7.407984,
52.291004
],
[
7.412572,
52.293926
],
[
7.4148655,
52.2949
],
[
7.4171596,
52.295387
],
[
7.420027,
52.295387
],
[
7.424615,
52.29587
],
[
7.429776,
52.293438
],
[
7.4320703,
52.29587
],
[
7.4320703,
52.29587
]
]
]
]
}
```

The 2 Polygons are direct neighbours and share a middle line, the left one gets cut out properly, the right one has the same Problem as the one from Euskirchen.

Again used `geojsonlint.com` to verify whats going on, and I can't see a problem with the objects, so I think there might be some kind of caching involved that's blocking from displaying / styling properly.

Interesting to note here: The Google Map knows that there should not be any Polygon, because the click event of the map object fires and not the one of the data layer.

Help / hints are really appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494474/google-maps-api-polygon-with-hole-in-center

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Dr. Molle,

I searched explicit for geoJSON Solutions, thanks for pointing in the right Direction, currently I'm regenerating the JSON Files (Germany takes roughly 30 Minutes) and will report after I tested this.

Comment: Just a friendly tip: we don't need to see the entire contents of a 1350 line json structure, and then another 900 line json structure.  Just give a minimal example, enough to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is very simple, as pointed to me by Dr. Molle.
[Google Maps API Polygon with "Hole" In Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494474/google-maps-api-polygon-with-hole-in-center)

The difference in rendering between Google Maps API and geojsonlint is also responsible for the differences.

When your Polygon points are Clockwise, all inner Polygons must be Counterclockwise to be left out, also by the style.

Just reverse the ordering of the points in the problematic inner Polygon.

In my case:

```
<?php
$array = array_reverse($array); 
?>
```