# How to define Google Map boundries and show shaded area outside boundry?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to display specific region based data on google map.For exa. if user selects "Atlanta" state then it will show all the data related to atlanta state and other parts of map will 
show the shaded area.I have searched a lot but not able to find solution for showing specific area based result(may not rectangular area) and other region as shaded.I have found similar functionality at http://www.redfin.com/homes-for-sale. Here they ask to select region and then based on region it shows data in clustered format within specific area.Please help on this.

Comment: I think I answered this question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956355/highlight-polygon-and-tint-rest-of-map-using-google-maps