# Highlight whole countries in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a general question about Google Maps. I want to use Google Maps just for germany, but of course the neighbor countries are shown as well. The border of germany is rarely visible.

Is there a possibility to fade out the other, not used countries?

Comment: Someone had a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956355/highlight-polygon-and-tint-rest-of-map-using-google-maps/2958856#2958856) a while back. If you have the coordinates for the border, you can invert a polygon using the method in my answer to that question. If you don't have the coordinates for the border, you can probably find them somewhere on the web, or draw the border yourself using google maps "My Places" and get the coordinates out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps API v3 Highlight Country Border without using Polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964573/google-maps-api-v3-highlight-country-border-without-using-polygons)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I was able to do this using the public [World Country Boundaries.kml](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk&pli=1#rows:id=1) Fusion Table.

You'll need to add it as a [Fusion Table Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) to your map.

---

Firstly initialize a map zoomed out right out, centered so we can see most countries:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(30,0),
  zoom: 2,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Next add the `FusionTablesLayer`:

```
var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk'
  },
  map: map,
  suppressInfoWindows: true
});
```

That looks like this:

[image: all countries]

---

With regard to:

> Is there a possibility to fade out the other, not used countries?

If you look at [the Fusion Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk&pli=1#rows:id=1) you'll see there are columns for `Name` and `ISO_2DIGIT`. We can filter on these by passing a `where` condition to the `FusionTablesLayer`, e.g:

```
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
    where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('US', 'GB', 'DE')"
  },
```

To give:

[image: filter countries with where]

Comment: Even if you change the color, this is pretty ugly. Especially as the layer goes over the country names.

Comment: You make a valid point, I've created an [issue here](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=1308).

Comment: Is it possible to choose the highlight colour?

Comment: @HayaRaed yes, see [Fusion Table Styles in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles).

Comment: FYI: **Fusion Tables are now deprecated** and will be removed next month.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this now since fusion tables are deprecated?

Answer (score 10):

For any one who ends up here in the future, this seems to now be handled very well by Google Charts, the latest implementation of the deprecated link above

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: is there a way to costumize the map and apply zooming and paning?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but: Google's deprecated Map Charts API looks like a better solution, if you do not need the map to be draggable:

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts

Example: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=-60,0,80,-35&chs=600x350&chld=CA-BC|CN|IT|GR|US-UT&chdl=Vancouver|Beijing|Torino|Athens|Salt+Lake+City&chco=B3BCC0|5781AE|FF0000|FFC726|885E80|518274&chtt=Last+Five+Olympic+Hosts&chm=f2010+Winter,000000,0,0,10|f2008+Summer,000000,0,1,10|f2008+Winter,000000,0,2,10,1,:-5:10|f2004+Summer,000000,0,3,10|f2004+Summer,000000,0,4,10

[image]

This api will continue to work at lest until April 2015: https://developers.google.com/chart/terms

> Important: The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been
>   officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work
>   as per our deprecation policy.

Answer (score 3):

**14 years** (!) after the [original feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953), Google has enabled [Data-driven styling](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-data-driven-styling).

> *One of the most commonly requested features you have asked for is access to the same boundaries and polygons used in Google Maps to build informative and engaging maps for your customers. Today, we are excited to announce the preview release of Data-driven styling for the Maps JavaScript API, which enables you to display and style Google boundaries.*

Here is a [demo](https://storage.googleapis.com/gmp-maps-demos/data-driven-styling/index.html) and the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/overview).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a map of Germany why not use this:

http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/germany/

Germany is already available

Comment: I need all the details which are containing in Google Maps.

Comment: can you please elaborate what is your exact requirement. No doubt google maps is always the answer, I am just wondering if your problem can be solved with other map type solution

Comment: Okay, I have coded a vector based map solution for a customer, which calculates the position of dots by long and lat and creates clusters (http://goo.gl/LvfFN - the map on the left side) . The customer wants additionally a gmaps implentation. Do you want to ask him why? I suppose this is not part of my initial question!

Comment: Then from the google maps prespective,  the best approach for you is to use google chart tools http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap.html, if you wanyt to leverage google maps then you need to overlays and highlight the germany map, like what is here for usa 
map
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_egroundoverlay.htm

Comment: Sad, that there seems to be no fancier solution :( But thanks for your efforts!

Comment: right, there is no fancier solution than this. you might still explore raphael js or the plugin I mentioned.

Comment: @defau1t thanks for fixing it - yesterday jvectormap.owl-hollow.net did not exist at all.

Comment: @Olli: that's true, the link was down but not 404. I saw someone down voted the post today so I was curious what could be the reason?

Comment: @defau1t can you fix the link in the post? ...owl-hollow... does not respond.

Comment: @martinjakubik: Here you go http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/germany/
if you find any post as useful make sure you vote up the answer :)

Comment: @defau1t I meant why don't you Edit your post and fix it... but I did it myself. Otherwise your post is wrong and people have to read down the comments to find the right link.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (API version 3) there seems to exist no possibility to increase border-thickness for single countries.