# Google Maps single country boundary

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to show country boundaries for only one country inside Google Map, just like it's done here:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea if it's possible to get such map using Google Maps and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The country polygons are available in FusionTables (specifically in the Natural Earth Data set).

Here is [an example showing South Africa](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=South%20Africa), it includes the individual states, if you don't want them, you should be able to find the country borders.  See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888958/country-boundries-using-google-map-api-v3)

Here is [an example showing just the country of South Africa](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_worldmap_linkto.html?lat=-29.989180&lng=25.474037&zoom=5&type=m&tableid=419167&tablequery=SELECT%20kml_4326%20FROM%20419167%20WHERE%20sovereignt%20%3D%20%27South%20Africa%27) from [this FusionTable](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=419167)

[This](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_SouthAfrica_styles.html) looks like the closest it can be styled to the image.

Comment: I've got some other examples in an answer to a similar question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17839407/21115).

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks this is great. How did you manage to style it? I followed the guidelines here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer but it seems that my styles are not getting applied. My SA map stays red no matter what.