# Google Maps - Get Province outline from Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When searching for a Province in Google Maps, it outlines the map and adds a icon on the Province.

How would you get that from google without having to draw it point by point ? Im sure it's available if its showing on their maps.

Here is an example:

[Western Cape, South Africa](https://maps.google.co.za/maps?hl=en&q=Western%20cape&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x1dcc5d887a698df3:0xe98e798f2136a28b,Western%20Cape&gl=za&ei=e3YjUKK2FcH-iwLUqoCACw&ved=0CD0Q8gEwBw)

Comment: I'm interested to see what you managed here. I am wanting to draw darker border lines for each province in SA but don't know where the borders exactly are. I have a question on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495576/how-to-draw-darker-borders-of-the-provinces-in-south-africa-with-google-maps-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is directly available through the API beyond what you can achieve with the [**styling wizard**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

To implement it yourself you'd need to find a shapefile for the areas of interest, store it in a spatially enabled database, (like PostgreSQL/PostGIS), and then load the relevant polygons, which you can style freely. Alternatively you can create a custom tile layer, [**like this**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html), (check the "density" box), or you may be able to load it using fusion tables, (not an entirely simple process).

Answer (score 1):

See this [similar question (doing the same thing for countries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary)

The answer can be applied to a province rather than a country.

[Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_SouthAfrica_styles.html) is the closest I could come to that styling.