# How to draw darker borders of the provinces in South Africa with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am using the `Google Maps API`. I am from South Africa and would like to show a map of South Africa with its borders for the provinces clearly marked. I have the map on my web page of South Africa but I have no idea how to get the borders of the provinces a bit more visible to the user.  There is dotted light grey lines which I am assuming is the border lines of the provinces?

My HTML container for the map:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var map;

     function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.49559749315654, 20.93444836718755),
               zoom: 8,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
               mapOptions);
     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

How do I get and draw the border lines of the provinces in South Africa darker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps single country boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary)

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the borders on your own.

Easiest way: use a FusionTableLayer, here is a FusionTable that contains the geometry of the provinces: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=16L-UK_1OZxGw6DlKR8V8yP4XZrtmNdOMugRRNrQ#map:id=3

Usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.49559749315654, 20.93444836718755),
               zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    //create the layer
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      //the layer doesn't need to be clickable
      clickable:false,
      query: {
      //column with the geometry
        select: "col2",
      //table-ID
        from: "16L-UK_1OZxGw6DlKR8V8yP4XZrtmNdOMugRRNrQ",
        where: ""
      },
      styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
        //border-color
        strokeColor: "#000000",
        //border-width
        strokeWeight: 2,
        //hide the fill
        fillOpacity:0.0001
      }}]
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```