# how to add or show zip code boundary Google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After searching zip code through geocoder i want to show boundary around that zip code region as shown in google maps. i have search 02201 as example in maps.google.com and it shows boundary around the whole zip region which indicates all the area under that zip range. here is my code which search zipcode using geocoder and i want to add boundary around that zip region.that i want to implement. please provide any solution. please see this link for image http://i46.tinypic.com/beyerq.jpg

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you even search this website first?

Comment: try to improve the format of your post by putting your description above the code sample. Next describe what your code sample does (it's not clear) and why it doesn't work. Tell us what you've tried so far, including at least googling the topic or reading documentation. If you want others to put effort into answering you, you have to put in effort first :) good luck.

Comment: sorry to miss understand you,

Comment: please tell me if you get the question or not?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html), but with a query to show only the specified zip code polygon.  [Like this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons).

Comment: please take a look on question.