# Google MAPS: colour active countries AND add markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-visualization

I'm building a travel social network website and I need to create a custom Google Maps based map.

In their profile users can:

- list the countries they've visited;
- for each country they can specify the cities they visited.

That means that on the same map I need to:

- colour the countries the user has visited;
- for each (now coloured) country he has visited, add a marker on the cities he went to.

As far as I've read,  I should use Google Charts API to get the countries coloured.
But I need an actual Google Map....any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
E.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Maps API v3.  See the documentation and search this site for how to:

- [add markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers)
- create [country polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary/11832316#11832316)