# Style Country - Google Maps API

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made a google styled map and now I want to add more features to it. The feature I'm trying to add is a way to style specific countries. I want to let my program select a country and then have that country appear differently on the map and stand out.

This is challenging because there are polygon ways to do this, but that would mean it is hardcoded and the country can't change. I want to be able to use this feature on different countries.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps single country boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this with styles; I think you'd need to generate map tiles with countries coloured and overlay those map tiles on top of what you have already.