# Change map opacity outside circle of Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm currently putting a circle on my map:

```
    var optionsCercle = {
        center: latlang,
        map: map,
        radius: 1000,
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        strokeWeight: 0
    };
    this.circ = new google.maps.Circle(optionsCercle);
```

Now I'm putting the inside of the circle to fillOpacity:0.1, but what I want to do is put everything on the map except the inside of the circle to fillOpacity:0.1. I want everything in my viewport except the circle to be "blurred out". How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An example that puts a circular "hole" over New York City (modified from [this Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)):

```
var citymap = {};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  population: 8143197
};

var cityCircle;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) { 
  var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
  var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
  var earthsradius = 3963; // 3963 is the radius of the earth in miles use 6371 if using kilometers
  var points = 32; 

  // find the raidus in lat/lon 
  var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
  var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r); 

  var extp = new Array(); 
  if (dir==1)   {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the ends
  else      {var start=points+1;var end=0}
  for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir) { 
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2)); 
    var ey = point.lng() + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
    var ex = point.lat() + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
    extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey)); 
    bounds.extend(extp[extp.length-1]);
  } 
  return extp;
}

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var outerbounds = [ // covers the (mercator projection) world
        new google.maps.LatLng(85,180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85,90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85,0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85,-90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85,-180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0,-180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85,-180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85,-90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85,0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85,90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85,180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0,180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85,180)];

    // options for the polygon
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      paths: [outerbounds,drawCircle(citymap['newyork'].center,10,-1)]
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Polygon(populationOptions);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_circle-simple_hole.html)

[image: screen shot]

Comment: related question: [Polygon of world map with a hole (google maps)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399025/polygon-of-world-map-with-a-hole-google-maps/)

Comment: How this can be done if I have geoJson of circle/polygon?

Comment: That is a new/different question

Answer (score 1):

`{-Lat, (Long-180)%180, 20037508.34-Radius}` workes well for me, Thx to Bahram Ardalan. Here my Code:

```
lat = 53;
lng = 10;
distance = 10 * 1000; // 10km

new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: this.map,
                center: {lat: -1 * lat, lng: (lng - 180 ) % 180},
                radius: 20037508.34 - distance
```

Answer (score -1):

Draw a circle in the opposite location and complement radius like

```
{-Lat, (Long-180)%180, 20037508.34-Radius}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for negative longitudes. -Math.sign(lng) * Math.abs((Math.abs(lng) - 180) % 180) works.