# Creating a "spotlight" effect using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a DistanceWidget & RadiusWidget to create a circle of a particular radius around a center point on a Google Map. I am now looking to create a "spotlight" effect similar to how it is being done on Housing.com (example at http://bit.ly/1vkyJtY) where the outside of the circle appears to be lightly masked and the inside of the circle is in full color. I have already created the circle and distance puller, I'm just trying to figure out how to go about creating the spotlight effect.

Comment: Did you zoom out on that link you posted?

Comment: it looks like you need to overlap a fixed or absolute positioned svg element onto the map. Then you can make a circular shaped hole into that svg and give it draggable handles

Comment: My question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736418/change-map-opacity-outside-circle-of-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/19746322#19746322