# IOS Google Maps. Polygon of entire world map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm trying to add a google maps polygon over the entire world in IOS. I pretty much followed this: [polygon with hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399025/polygon-of-world-map-with-a-hole-google-maps)

I'm using these coordinates for the entire world:

```
var worldBounds = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180)
  ];
```

The polygon covers the mercator projection of the world correctly. But when I scroll horizontally (infinite scrolling) and the polygon's bounds are hit then half of my screen looks without the polygon applied and the other half looks like with the polygon applied. Once I scroll further horizontally it looks fine. I would like to have the polygon's effect continuously applied.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]