# Does Google Maps API incorrectly interpret -90 and 90 lat?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, latitude-longitude

I try to circumscribe the whole map in a rectangle but the points shift up and down too much! How do I deal with it?

```
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { zoom: 5, center: { lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268 }, mapTypeId: "terrain" });
    const rectCoordinates = [
        { lat: 90, lng: -180 }, { lat: 90, lng: 180 }, { lat: -90, lng: 180 }, { lat: -90, lng: -180 },
    ];
    const rect = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: rectCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    rect.setMap(map);
```

[image]

Comment: Related question: [Google Map API v3 shade everything EXCEPT for polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130323/google-map-api-v3-shade-everything-except-for-polygon)

Comment: Relate question [Change map opacity outside circle of Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736418/change-map-opacity-outside-circle-of-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Comment: Use +/-85 degrees for the maximum latitude with the Mercator projection.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wk1vpLy6/1/)